# Emulate click in Chrome settings page

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, applescript

I want to make a script to open my No.1 chrome history address link,

I can arrive the page by input 「chrome://history」to the chrome location bar by applescript.

But, I cant click the No.1 address by applescript or javascript, looks like chrome do some restriction.

Anyone have solutions? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You could use `execute javascript` in a `tell application "Google Chrome"`-block, however, the HTML is quite nested and may be difficult to get the right `href`, but I think this could be a good starting point.

Comment: it is a pity that in chrome setting page, I cant execute javascript. And looks like google use many custom tag in html, this line even dont in dom object.